# MOSFET circuit how to continue

Tags: voltage, mosfet, circuit-analysis, current, analog

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9eG0b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I assumed the MOSFET operates in the ohmic region.

Id = 1/2k × VDS(VGS - VTH - VDS / 2) and for VTH = 1 V I get 2 results ID1 = 3 mA. Okay.
ID2 = -5 mA. Not okay.

So how do I continue from here? How can I prove my assumption is correct or am I done here?

Comment: what is the purpose of R3?

Comment: The gate of your Mosfet is at 0V so the Mosfet is turned off and does not conduct.

Comment: What do you know how to calculate or estimate? Vgs is known (5V). Ids = (5-Vds) / 1k. Or, you could use the voltage divider equation and say that Vds = 5V * Rds / (Rds + 1k). Then once you have Vds you can easily get Ids.

Comment: Gate of mosfet is tied to 5V. Source is tied to GND. Therefore Vgs = 5V, and OP should compare the Vgs(th) to 5V to help decide whether the mosfet is fully off, fully on (ohmic region) or in between.

Answer (score 1):

At `Id=3mA`, the voltage drop over R2 is 3V. Therefore, `Vds = 5V-3V = 2V`. This in turn means that `Vds < Vgs-Vth = 5V-1V = 4V`. The MOSFET therefore operates in the ohmic region and your assumption was correct.